# Can we use "contextual search" for MobileFirst Platform 7.0 Operational Analytics?(Can we limit the client logs by minitues?)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In Worklight v6.1, analytics search view has "contextual search". It runs a new search that will return events that occurred in the same time frame. This is useful for trouble shooting of fatal or error logs.

In MFP Foundation v7.0, I see just "Download all logs for this device". It's tough to find related events.

Does MFP Foundation the have same function? If not, is there any way to run similar search?

---

It seems I should change my question more specifically.
In the analytics 7.0 console, it seems we can limit the logs only by date. Is there any way to limit the logs by minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the analytics 7.0 console you can go to the search tab. There you can search on client logs or server logs. For client you have the option to filter on keywords, application, environment, level, packages, and date range. For server you can filter on keywords, server, level, and date range.

Seems like contextual search is mostly just find your error and put in the date range to limit the logs.

You can submit request for enhancements at https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help

Comment: Thanks, Chevy. I think contextual search could limit the logs in the minutes, not date. Is there any way to limit the logs in minute range?

Comment: No I do not see a way. It looks like date is as small as you can go. Is limiting to minutes really necessary? A full day of logs is not that bad if you know what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for late response. Yes, I need to limit logs in minutes.  In one day, there are hundreds of logs for one device. But I want to look logs in a few minutes duration before crash or error occured.

Comment: If you need this feature I added the link to request a feature to my answer.